# Is there a shortcut to open folders up in a new window?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

With directories you can right click -> `Open in new window`, however I would like to know whether there is an easier shortcut, because this is an action that I perform all the time.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hold down `Ctrl` and double click the file/folder to open in a new window.

You can also hold `Ctrl` and hit `Enter` on a highlighted folder to accomplish the same thing (In case you like to browse with your keyboard)

Let me know if thats what you needed!

Comment: Thank you, this does work for normal files, although, is there a short cut that works for the sidebar folders too? Screenshot of sidebar >  [link](https://puu.sh/uD8AM/c1ce6ebe6b.png)

Comment: @leonW I am not sure.  From what I can find so far, you cannot do it with native Windows Explorer.  Although, I will be sure to let you know if I find something.

Comment: @LeonW No problem, feel free to share if you figure anything out as well!

Comment: `Ctrl` and double click the file/folder seems only to work on the left side. If I do that on the right side in my file explorer, it does not open a new windows. `Ctrl` and `Enter` works also on the right side. (Win 10 build 1803).

Comment: CTRL+ENTER: this is the shortcut of the year! +10

Comment: @LeonW regarding "normal files", some may have other special functions or behavior coded into the software.  For example, Office files (e.g., .docx, .xlsx, etc) launch in safe-mode when holding down the `Ctrl` key during launch.

Answer (score 9):

`C:\Users\USER-NAME\Downloads`

in shortcut properties, the type target is 'Folder', and this open in same window, to change behavior put parameter and path in field 'Target':

before path

`C:\Windows\explorer.exe /n,`

like this

`C:\Windows\explorer.exe /n, "C:\Users\USER-NAME\Downloads"`

or

`C:\Windows\explorer.exe /n, C:\Users\USER-NAME\Downloads`

this change target type to application located to explorer then explorer.exe get's parameter N to open your custom path to  folder in new window.

Comment: just `explorer C:\Users\USER-NAME\Downloads` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Selecting the folder on the left, ctrl + n, alt + tab, enter.

Shoutout to shaunessyqueen https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/is-there-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-open-a-folder-in-a/c45311d0-7948-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1

Answer (score 2):

You can change the settings for Windows Explorer so that it always opens folders in a new window. To do this, start by going into the View tab and then click Options:

[image]

When you click on Options, a "Folder Options" window will open. You can then click "Open each folder in its own window" and then click OK or Apply to save the settings:

[image]

Once you've done this, every time you double-click on a folder it will open in a new window. You can always change this setting back by doing the same thing and selecting "Open each folder in the same window".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed instructions. Although I was looking for a shortcut rather than a permanent setting, I will be sure to use this trick in the future when organising files and folders. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I came here looking for an answer but eventually figured it out myself.

So for any folder ctrl+right click and then just press e.

Edit: I'm just 4 years too late.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else stumbles open this post: I just use ctrl + n with nothing selected to open a new window of the current window, and then I click the sidebar folder I would like to open. Alternatively, you could use Auto Hot Key to map a few shortcuts to common folders (for example, I like to use ctrl + windows key + d for documents).

Answer (score 0):

When wanting to use `C:\Windows\explorer.exe /n,` (full path) in a shortcut, if you just enter `explorer /n,`, Windows will automatically convert this to the full path when the shortcut is saved.